# How to set line-height for this css?

Tags: css

```
.mainheading 
{ 
  font-weight: 700;
  font-style: normal; 
  position: relative; 
  padding-bottom: 1.33333rem;
  display: table; 
  line-height: 1.1; 
} 

.mainheading::after 
{ 
  content:''; 
  display: block; 
  position: absolute; 
  border-bottom: 2px solid #72bf44; 
  min-width: 110px; 
  width: 70%; 
  bottom: 0; 
  left: 0.2rem; 
}
```

I am working on a reporting tool and I tried adding this css to the label

But the line-height is not working.
Suggest me where I went wrong

Comment: Its the space between lines

Comment: If you use just a number for the line-height, the font-size is multiplied with that number for the line-height. This seems to work just fine with the posted code, so unless you have more *specific* styles elsewhere, it's working

Comment: @Madhu the best way to debug CSS is to open your browser's dev-tools (F12 usually) and inspect that element; look at the css being applied to it to see if your styles are being applied or not and/or over-written.  You can also manually edit the CSS here (locally) to preview changes.

Comment: I have other styles too. May be that's overriding.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the shown HTML is invalid even if used in a proper context such as the label tag is not self closing and there is no caption attribute.

Comment: That's a tool I am using and I have class,id as attributes for the element label. I wrote it to explain the actual thing. Will edit my question

Comment: Now your question is worse cause you supply no HTML at all: [mcve]

Comment: Can you be more specific? What you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

With your initial code you're basically creating a new HTML tag `<Label>` with an attribute `Class`. CSS can read the `class` and `id` with the selectors `.` and `#`. You can always select an attribute with the CSS [attribute selector](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp), in your case:

```
label[Class="mainheading"] {
  /* style */
}
```

I recommend you stick with `class` and `id` instead of `Class` and `ID`, like so:

```
<label caption="Main Report" class="mainheading" id="lblDashboardsummary">Hello</label>
```

And in the CSS file just do

```
label.mainheading
```

Comment: Wrong, html is NOT case-sensitive: https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html-markup-20120315/documents.html#case-insensitivity

Comment: And the OP's code looks a lot like something from a template or serverside code, that is converted to HTML

Comment: Its my mistake while writing the code. I am using a reporting tool and "class" has no issue with it

Comment: I have clarified my answer

Answer (score 0):

```css
.mainheading 
{ 
  font-weight: 700;
  font-style: normal; 
  position: relative; 
  padding-bottom: 1.33333rem;
  display: table; 
  line-height: 0; 
} 

.mainheading::after 
{ 
  content:''; 
  display: block; 
  position: absolute; 
  border-bottom: 2px solid #72bf44; 
  min-width: 110px; 
  width: 70%; 
  bottom: 0; 
  left: 0.2rem; 
}
```

```html
<label caption="Main Report"    class="mainheading"
    id="lblDashboardsummary">Your Text</label>
```

> It is good coding practice to write HTML attributes in lowercase.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Wrong, html is NOT case-sensitive: https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html-markup-20120315/documents.html#case-insensitivity

Comment: Yes. that's why I have written have to be, not must to be. It is good practice to write in lower case.

Comment: 'have to be' and 'must be' is the same to me.. please edit it

Comment: Its my mistake while writing the code. I am using a reporting tool and "class" has no issue with it

Comment: The label element does not have a caption attribute.